# Scrapy stats Crawled pages and pages/min

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Could someone help me understand scrapy stats.
I'm trying to optimize the scrapy crawling speed for an aws instance.
My current scrapy crawl speed is `INFO: Crawled 32429 pages (at 72 pages/min), scraped 197 items (at 0 items/min)`
If scrapy is crawling at 72 pages/min what is 32429 pages?  Definitely not 32429 pages/sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Crawled X pages` it is total amount of HTTP responses that Scrapy received while crawling.

FYI, [`logstats` module](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e748ca50ca3e83ac703e02538a27236fedd53a7d/scrapy/contrib/logstats.py) is responsible for the report that you see on the console.

Comment: Oh the total pages! TY